# ES_Extended locale.lua attempted to call string value

Tags: lua, fivem, esx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAbZk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySno9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVgg8.png)

i get this error everytime it tries to call the funtion _U and add the translated string to the esx:notification. pls help i am not that good att lua. locale.lua es_extended

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: The random `_` before `(str, ...)` is probably not what you want, it calls `_`. Where did you get that code from? Did you replace something by accident with `_`?

Answer (score 0):

A easier way to do it is to change your locales-system.

-> first create a locales folder an write the path in your fxmanifest.lua or __ressource.lua

-> create a en.lua in your locales folder and build it like this:

```
Locales['en'] = {
   ['NAME'] = 'WORD',
}
```

-> now you can use it like this `ESX.ShowNotification(_U('NAME'))` in your client and like this `TriggerClientEvent('esx:showNotification', source, _U('NAME')` in your server